# How to use window, document event in reactjs and createElement like appendChild

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am confuse some idea about reactjs need to solve,

I have try it first vanilla javascript and I need the same design also reactjs

See my snippet  below.

**For Vanilla Js**

```
document.onmousemove = myFunction;

function myFunction(e){
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  document.body.appendChild(span);

  span.setAttribute('style', `width: 20px; height: 20px; background: red; position: absolute; top: ${e.clientY}px; left: ${e.clientX}px`)
}
```

and for 
reactjs I have tried,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    setTop: '',
    setLeft: '',

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.onmousemove = this.myFunction;
  }
  myFunction = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      setTop: e.clientY,
      setLeft: e.clientX
    });


  }
  render() {
    const spanStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '20px',
      height: '20px',
      background: 'red',
      top: this.state.setTop + 'px',
      left: this.state.setLeft + 'px'
    }
    return ( <
      div className = "App" >
      <
      span style = {
        spanStyle
      } > < /span> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , window.root)
```

for ReactJs the span tag not increasing which vanilla js does and one thing for reactjs the code doesn't make good sense I need pure idea for reactjs this code, if without component and short code concept that will me fine.

Comment: You aren't using the component state correctly.  Read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

I have created code on codeSandBox, [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fill-span-2qljj).

This will answer your question. I have made exact copy of your vanilla code with React.

The issue was with your code you were not creating new `span`, in your code we have only one `span` and its style is keep on updating as the mouse move.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      divs: []
    };

    this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.myFunction.bind(this), false);
  }

  myFunction(e) {
    let style = {
      width: "20px",
      height: "20px",
      background: "red",
      position: "absolute",
      top: `${e.clientY}px`,
      left: `${e.clientX}px`
    };

    let s = <span style={style} />;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      divs: [...prevState.divs, s]
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        Test loadeed.
        {this.state.divs}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Just add `<Test />` inside your App.js file and you will get what you want.